# How to put operator domain filter?

Tags: xml, odoo, operator-keyword

How could I put operator `'<'` to domain filter in xml openerp v7?

For example, I want to put `'<'` on my filter:

```
domain="[('qty_available','<','0')]"
```

but when I put `'<'`, openerp gives me an error validate code.

I tried put `'>'` openerp can be validate code.

So how could I put `'<'` on xml code?

Answer (score 0):

Finally this solution for me. Thanks

```
> use &gt;

< use &lt;

<= use &lt;=

>= use &gt;=
```